# How could I resolve the sleep spell action when using Minions in 5E?

Tags: dnd-5e

I use Minions in my 5E campaign at times.  I use them as canon fodder and their hit points are non-existent.  Meaning, they have an AC of X and if the PC lands any hit, they are dead.

(I read that in 4E that Minions had only 1 hit point.)

What are the ways I could resolve the Sleep Spell action if the PC's snuck up on a campsite or cave with multiple Minions who were unaware of their presence?

Looking for Rules as Intended. (only because I don't believe their is RAW)

Comment: Do you mean that you use a ruleset of your design for how these minions work based on 4e, or something else? I don't believe a minion that works like that exists in 5e, instead being just weaker monsters, such as a vampire's bats, or an elder brain's thralls

Comment: I use 5E.  I like adding Minions for epic show downs to add drama and challenge to the scene without making it too difficult for the PC's.

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't really offer up a Rules as Written OR Rules as Intended answer on this, because Minions (as in 4E) don't exist in 5E. So no rules exist and no intentions have been established or can be deduced for something that doesn't exist. It's kinda like asking how the designers intended a Hyperdrive or Lightsaber to function in D&D 5E. If you're looking for ideas, might I suggest trying a forum (like giantitp or enworld) or reddit? The Stack works best when there is an actual answer to be had...

Comment: @guildsbounty I'm unsure whether "There is no answer because this is a houserule/homebrew" is actually the valid answer here. Your comment *could* be turned into that if you wanted

Comment: @NightOwl you can message me in the [general chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) I have used a similar homebrew before.